# Jquery form :input

Tags: jquery-validate

Is there a "simple" way to ensure that ALL the inputs in a form have "an entry".  I need/want to disable the submit button unless all inputs have a value they are all input type=text.  I assume it is something like for each but I am not very good at the for each in JQuery.  Possible problem is that the inputs are "dynamically" generated by sortables?  All I need to know is is there a value in every input field.  The "real" validation is done elsewhere.

So is it something like:

```
$j('#button').click(function (){
each(function(:input){
//check the length in here?
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this post useful  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/enable-disable-submit-depending-on-filled-out-form?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#button").click(function(event) {
    var valid = true;
    $(":input").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    if (!valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Should work.

First part grabs the element with `id` of `button`, then assigns a function to the `onclick` event.  Second part grabs all input fields, and run a function on each of them. Then you get the length of the value for each.

The `$(this)` works since the function is being applied to a specific element on the page, and will always get you the current element.

Comment: Hi Slokun, as you said "should work" may be it does with "proper" Jquery, but I can't get it to - totally work .  I have tried a number of things/ variations but the moment I use if(!valid) then the whole page refreshes etc.  I cant get a result from if(!valid) {alert('this')} else{ alert('that')} I always get the "false" statment.  The first part i.e. the each function works I know that will keep playing... Thanks

Comment: Oh had to change to $j("#tstform :input[type='text']").each(function(index) {... as it way firing for "every" form on the page

Comment: @russp So, did it work with the different selector? And yeah, if you don't specify the form the inputs are in, it will grab everything on the page.